# How can I scale down a "spinkit" spinner to blend in better with my text size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using [`react-spinkit`](http://kyleamathews.github.io/react-spinkit/)/[`spinkit`](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) to create a `three-bounce` spinner that I want to use next to some text in place a static ellipsis.

Here is my current Typescript react code:

```
<div style={ {display:"flex", flexDirection:"row"} }>
  <div>Loading server details</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <Spinner spinnerName='three-bounce' />
</div>;
```

It works well, but the spinner looks too big:

[image]

It looks especially out of place on an iPhone.

How can I scale down the spinner to about half that size?

(But in a "relative" kind of way, I don't want to specify pixel sizes.)

I tried surrounding the spinner element with div setting the width and height css style to 50%:

```
  <div style={ {width:"50%", height:"50%"} }>
    <Spinner spinnerName='three-bounce'/>
  </div>
```

But that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

After lookin at the css source for `react-spinkit`, I ended up adding this to my global css file:

```
.sk-three-bounce > div {
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}
```

It doesn't do it in a "relative" way, but then neither does spinkit (the original is just hardcoded to `18px`).